# XPath expression to Select all labels not nested within a UL tag

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have a simple question regarding an XPath expression to ask, my HTML looks like this. I am wanting to select ONLY the label which is a child of DT.

```
<div class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
<dl class="last">
<dt>
<ul>
<label class="required">Available Grip Sizes<em>*</em></label>
</ul>
<div><label>other label</label></div>
</dt> 

<dt>
<label>Would you like this racket restrung?</label>
</dt>

<dt>
<label>String Tension</label>
</dt>
</dl>
</div>

My XPath expression: .//div[@id='product-options-wrapper']//dt/label"
```

I did try using a [not(@class)] expression which in this particular scenario would work, however I cannot use this in my project as I am using the same xpath on multiple documents.

So I want my query to be.. SELECT ALL LABELS EXCEPT NOT A CHILD OF UL / NESTED WITHIN A UL

Thank you ever so much

Also, can anybody reference a good site for learning more in depth XPath query/expressions?

Comment: Does *all except not a child* means *all children*?

Answer (score 0):

If *'all except not a child of ul'* means *'all which are children of ul'* then XPath looks like

```
//div[@id='product-options-wrapper']//dt/ul//label
```

Getting these labels with HtmlAgilityPack will look like

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_html_file);
string xpath = "//div[@id='product-options-wrapper']//dt/ul//label";
var labels = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Result is

```
<label class="required">Available Grip Sizes<em>*</em></label>
```

---

UPDATE: After you completely changed question, solution will be (actually you have correct XPath for this requirement)

```
//div[@id='product-options-wrapper']//dt/label
```

Result is

```
<label>Would you like this racket restrung?</label>
<label>String Tension</label>
```

Comment: Hi Sergev, sorry I had to edit my original post. I want to only select labels which are direct children of a DT tag, so in my scenario I want to select only two labels.

Comment: @user3091209 OK, updated answer. Actually now its not clear what problem you have with your query

Comment: Hi Sergev, again sorry for the poor description, what I actually want to do is select all labels, which are direct children of DT, where the sibling element <dd> does not contain a <ul> tag.

So in this scenario, only two tags are selected.

<dl class="last">
<dt>
    <label class="required">Grip Size<em>*</em></label>
</dt>
<dd>
    <div class="input-box"><ul class="options-list"><!-- CODE --></ul></div>
</dd>
                                
<dt>
    <label>Racket Re-String</label>
</dt>
                                
<dt>
<label>Stringing Tension</label>
</dt>
</dl>

Comment: @user3091209 you have extremely poor description of your intent. I will wait a little to make sure your last requirement will not change

Comment: Apologies Sergev, I am confident my last comment is what I wish to achieve. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: @user3091209 OK, then query should look like `//div[@id='product-options-wrapper']//dt[not(ul)]/label`